# Create coordinate point list by using list of coordinate in x and y axis

Tags: matlab, vector, coordinates

I have this number:

```
x = [-4 -3.1 -2.2 -1.3 -0.4 0.5 1.4 2.3 3.2 4.1]
```

and

```
y = [0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5]
```

I want to create a list of coordinate in 2 columns [x y] by using those numbers in the simplest cleverest way and not using a loop.

Here is the example of creating it by using loop:

```
for h=1:11
    for j=1:11
        gridCoord((h-1)*11+j,1)=x(1,j);
        gridCoord((h-1)*11+j,2)=y(1,h);
    end
end
```

** The coordinate moves in x-direction first.

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't run as posted.

Comment: sorry the x should be 11 column, have to add another 0ne that is = 5. Thanks. x = [-4 -3.1 -2.2 -1.3 -0.4 0.5 1.4 2.3 3.2 4.1 5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to achieve what you want

```
[yy, xx] = meshgrid(y, x);
gridCoord = [xx(:), yy(:)]
```

> **NOTE**: Ordinarily, you will see `meshgrid` examples using `[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y)`; however, since you specify that you want it to be row major (changing `x` first), I have reversed the order since by default `meshgrid` is column major (changes the first argument first). You could achieve the same effect by simply taking the transpose of `xx` and `yy` prior to concatenating them into `gridCoord`.

Comment: You can also use `ndgrid` and you don't need to reverse. That's probably more natural